# How to solve a "X is not a Java identifier" issue in Hibernate?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, java-ee-6

I began working on a project in Hibernate and I encountered this strange error as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I don't really know what is the problem **with jboss.jms.api.2.0.spec** .
I downloaded the jar files from [here](https://javajee.com/downloading-hibernate-jar-files) and put them in my project.

What can I try next?

Comment: Why have you downloaded the files there? Do you want to use Hibernate 4? Do you want to develop for JBoss?

Comment: I think u  are talking about the place of jar files.I put them in downloads randomly!

Comment: Well, even if I dismiss the point why you shouldn't be uploading pictures here, I even can't read the text on that snippet.

Comment: @MorningFlower I think You have chosen a place form where to download the files randomly :) Use Hibernate 5 and Maven or Gradle please.